# My sound has been disabled

Tags: sound

I want to enable my sound, which is in disabled state. When i click at sound preferences, it do not respond. What is he possible remedy. I am using ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot of what the control looks like? You can insert screenshot by editing your posts and press the icon for including images.

Comment: i am pressing My print screen button but nothing happens

Comment: What happens if you paste into an image editor after you pressed print screen?

Comment: Check that your user has permission to configure audio devices. To take an screenshots I recommend installing shutter.

Comment: @Tariq_Malhi any news?

Answer (score 1):

There are some debugging hints on the wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio